# Initializing a non-numeric variable in Java

Tags: java, variables, text, adventure

To practice using if else, do while, and switch statements, I was making a small text adventure game where a user would be able to input their name, gain a randomly generated profession, and be assigned a randomly generated quest. however, halfway though the second goal, the java development program I was using continually said that one of my variables "might not have been initialized".

This is what i have for the code so far:

============

```
import java.util.*;
public class Adventure1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //initialize variables
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keyboardYN = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keyboard2YN = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name = "";

        char userInput;
        char userYN;
        char user2YN;

        int dieRoll = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
        char outputType;

        char Mage;
        char Soldier;
        char Explorer;
        char howTo;

        //exeternal documation
        System.out.println("The First Adventure by K. Konieczny ");
        System.out.println();

        //player name
        do
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("What is your name: ");
            name = keyboard.nextLine();
            //prompt
            System.out.print("So your name is " + name + "? Are you sure y/n : ");
            userYN = keyboardYN.nextLine().charAt(0);
            System.out.println();
            if(userYN == 'y')
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Type in your real name.");
            }

            }//end do
        while(userYN == 'n');

        //narration pt. 1
        System.out.println("You, " + name +
                           " have just been named the greatest, uh, what was it again?");
        System.out.println();

        //specialization
        System.out.print("Roll the dice to decide what your profession is? y/n : ");
        user2YN = keyboard2YN.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if(user2YN == 'y')
           {
            switch (dieRoll)
            {
                case '0':
                case '1':
                case '2': outputType = Mage;
                case '3':
                case '4':
                case '5': outputType = Soldier;
                case '6':
                case '7':
                case '8': outputType = Explorer;
                default : outputType = howTo;
            }//end switch
            System.out.println("Oh right, you are the greatest " + outputType + " in the town.");

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("I must be thinking of someone else then.");
            }

        //get quest


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("End of program");
    }//end main
}//end class
```

============

The error message i get reads "variable Mage might not have been initialized."

I don't have much coding experience, and was wondering what I did wrong and how I could fix it in future programs.

Comment: What line/variable are you getting this error on?

Comment: Why do you have 3 scanner's on `System.in`?

Comment: First of all you have to initialize variables before using them. You can initialized it with `null` or other value. This variable have to be put in some state.

If I were you I would use some IDE for easier coding. I recommend Intellij IDEA. It can be downloaded for free from Intellij website.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
char Mage;
// ...
case '2': outputType = Mage;
```

What is the value of `Mage` at that point? The compiler is warning you that the variable has not been initialized.

You might want to initialize `Mage` to some value such as:

```
char Mage = '0';
```

Or most likely you want a `String` representation of `Mage`:

```
String outputType;
String mage = "Mage";
String soldier = "Soldier";
String explorer = "Explorer";
// ...
switch (dieRoll) {
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2': outputType = mage; 
              break;
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5': outputType = soldier; 
              break;
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8': outputType = explorer;
              break;
    default : outputType = "Oops";
}
```

Comment: according to the following print `you are the greatest " + outputType + " in the town."`, I assume `Mage`should be a String containing the value `"Mage"`

Comment: @jhamon You are right. I edited my answer.